# What are the physical quantities represented by the physical conservation ports in Simmechanics?

Tags: matlab, simulink, modeling, simscape, simmechanics

What are the physical quantities represented by the physical conservation ports in Simmechanics? Cf. this picture from the [Simscape user guide](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/physmod/simscape/simscape_ug.pdf).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you refer to the first or second generation SimMechanics. The [documentation page on connection ports](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/connectionport.html) lists the different types:

[image]

The various concepts relating to each type of port is detailed in the SimMechanics documentation. For example, see [Representing Frames](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ug/representing-frames.html) for what frame ports are all about.